# JAVA: How to minus the currentime and the data time that has been stored in database.?

Tags: java, sql, fingerprint, digital, persona

I'm developing a fingerprint based attendance system using Java and i don't know how to automatically logout after the 2nd time around of scanning the same fingerprint data. The question is how to minus the current time and the time that has been stored in the database.

here is my code

```
  String sqlReports ="SELECT 
  sch_id='"+id.getText()+"',name,date,timein,timeout FROM reports";
  Statement st = cn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlReports);              
  while(rs.next()){
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a"); 
  out.setText(sdf.format(rs.getString("timeout")));
  String r= sdf.format(cal.getTime());

if (cal.getTime() - out.getText() > 10) {
```

//Updatesqlhere

```
        }`
```

Comment: What are you asking about here? How to do time calculations or...? Please add the code that is causing the issue so we get some more context.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean by fingerprint data. Can you specify how you get the current time and the time stamp from your data? Is it UTC? What is the format?
What have you tried and found so far?

Comment: What's the database table structure? And in Java, do you have a `java.util.Date`?

Comment: What's the database engine? DB2, PostgreSQL, Informix, etc.

Comment: here is my code : and i'm getting error

Comment: String sqlReports ="SELECT sch_id='"+id.getText()+"',name,date,timein,timeout FROM reports";
               Statement st = cn.createStatement();
               ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlReports);              
               while(rs.next()){
                 
                  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a"); 
                  out.setText(sdf.format(rs.getString("timeout")));
                  String r= sdf.format(cal.getTime());
                
                    if (cal.getTime() - out.getText() > 10) {
              
         }

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Post code in the question and not as a comment.

Comment: the error is bad operand types  for binary operator '-'

Comment: You can't format a string with `SimpleDateFormat.format()`, what type is `timeout` in  the database? Also, we don't know the type of `cal`and `out`. Please try to post a complete example.

Comment: varchar=timeout . cal is the current time .out is the textfield which i try to retrieve in the database